# Can Google Cloud Endpoints Be Hit Using Task Queues?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have an app engine task queue that tries to call a cloud endpoint, but when I see the task queue fire off it gets a 404. I verified the endpoint is configured for post:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "sendemail", path = "sendemail", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
```

and I am queueing like this:

```
TaskOptions lOptions = TaskOptions.Builder.withUrl("/_ah/api/email/v1/sendemail");
```

I can hit the endpoint using the endpoint explorer, what am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably defaulting to get method try adding method POST or making endspoints method get.

```
withUrl("....").method(Method.POST)
```

Comment: I've tried that as well, no dice. For some reason it's as if it can't get to the URL. I can hit it from a REST client outside of App Engine and if I look at what the API explorer does it also makes a plain POST request. Any other ideas? have you tried this and got it working? Thanks!

Comment: yeah, I tried adding a task with endpoint but on python, and it's working.

Comment: I'm on Java so I wonder why it's different? Or maybe I am doing something wrong, I will try it today to see if I can get a simple example to work.

Comment: I would think it's the same, what does the declaration of endpoints look like?

Comment: I've finally got around to trying this and the problem I have run into is that I am trying to call an endpoint from a cron job or task queue, these seems to only be able to hit http addresses and endpoints have to be https.

Comment: Yeah, it's not going to work unless you use HTTPS. If this is within the same app, why are you trying to call your API? That's going to be inefficient. Just use the Endpoints method directly within your task. Endpoints classes are regular code that can be called via the API surface or called from other Java code within your app.

Comment: @DanHolevoet But isn't that solution just putting a wrapper on an endpoint because the endpoint can't be accessed via https? Since the functionality I need happens in the endpoint I don't actually need any code to be outside of it.

I appreciate the work around and I know that will technically work, but I feel like this should be possible the way I am trying to do it, maybe a feature for the future. Thanks for answering, I really appreciate it!

Comment: I guess it depends on how you slice it. To me, if you're calling the code from the same logical piece of the app (which it is, if it has access to the same Java source), you're better off calling it without going through Endpoints.

Comment: @DanHolevoet I agree, it would be great to just call it via Java, but how do you handle situations where you need more than 30 seconds to complete the task?

Comment: Spin up a task in the regular fashion (i.e. write your own task handler), but don't try and make requests via the public API surface.